# How to Stream Video from url autometically buffere and play on lower speed of internet in objective c

Tags: ios

Here is my code:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myglams.com/UserUpload/vv/oSiFevyNHM.mp4"];

 moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
 [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 380, 150)];
 [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
 moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
 moviePlayerController.allowsAirPlay = YES;
 moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay =YES;
 moviePlayerController.controlStyle  = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
 [moviePlayerController play];//  cannot stream automatically its needs many play every time
```

Comment: Please if you know the answer then tell me i need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option for play videos is `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer` using `currentItem.loadedTimeRanges` observer.

Example

```
    void *kTimeRangesKVO1 = &kTimeRangesKVO1;

    playerView = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
    layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:playerView];

    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoContentPlayer.frame.size.width, videoContentPlayer.frame.size.height);
    [layer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
    [videoContentPlayer.layer insertSublayer:layer below:labelTime.layer];

    [playerView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:kTimeRangesKVO1];


    // the callback method
    - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    {
        if (kTimeRangesKVO1 == context) {
            NSArray *timeRanges = (NSArray*)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
            if (timeRanges && [timeRanges count]) {
                CMTimeRange timerange=[[timeRanges objectAtIndex:0]CMTimeRangeValue];
                float currentBufferDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeAdd(timerange.start, timerange.duration));
                CMTime duration = playerView.currentItem.asset.duration;
                float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);

                //your code here with your rules.
            }
        }
    }
```

Remember remove your observer with `removeObserver` something like `[playerView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.loadedTimeRanges"];`

Comment: @MiteshMungara you are using `inserSublayer`? check mi answer.

Comment: playerView = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:URL];
    layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:playerView];
    [playerView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:kTimeRangesKVO1];
    layer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer: layer];